# Using a 2d array as a lookup table vs. calculating click

Tags: javascript, lookup-tables

I have a canvas with a width of 1000 and a height of 600.  Within this canvas I have 300-500 rectangle tiles each with their own id. I can detect mouse coordinates within the canvas but I have to either have a 1000 by 600 2D array as a look-up table or run an algorithm to find if the coordinates fall within a tile. This is javascript so it is all within a browser. Is a 1000 by 600 2D array too much for the browser to handle? Implementation wise the look-up table is by far the easier solution(and probably faster), but is the trade-off in space too much?

Comment: If it's JavaScript, why is the question tagged with Java? Java != JavaScript.

Comment: Calculating the click will likely be a issue of two substractions (for getting the origin) and two divisions for getting the cell/rectangle. Does not look that hard to me to add complexity. Is there anything that I am missing?

Comment: It's tagged as javascript...

Comment: @CynicalOptimist: yes, because I edited the tags to fix them. It was tagged Java.

Comment: If they each have their own ID, why aren't you just using that?  Can you clarify what you're trying to accomplish?  You're presenting a dichotomy, when there may be other solutions?

Comment: you're right there may be other solutions though those where to two I saw as viable. They have individual IDs but there is no way to know which element is being selected with the mouse.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks, I meant to put it as javascript

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably depend on numbers.

If there are **many** clicks, and the position of the targets doesn't change, it *might* be more efficient to pre-calculate the mapping as you're suggesting.

But, the cost of generating the initial mapping is relatively high, and if the display changes you incur that cost again (thought there are ways to mitigate that). My **guess** is that it is probably quicker to loop over the targets and do the maths for each click, since the math shouldn't be very complex/intensive when it's only rectangles.

I'd say, use whatever is easiest for you to implement. If it's not performant enough (or, you just want to give it a go), **then** try an alternative and compare them.

Comment: "If there are many clicks, and the position of the targets doesn't change, it might be more efficient to pre-calculate the mapping as you're suggesting." this is exactly the case. I'll try the lookup table first!